# https://localhost returned ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (secure connection)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, localhost

I am using Node and express.js to build my server and I setup my https server (essentially) like this:

```
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./credentials/rippal.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./credentials/rippal.crt', 'utf8');
const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

const app = express();
setup(app, config);

let httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app)

httpsServer.listen(3333, function () { 
    console.log("Server listening on port 3333...\n");
});
```

with self-signed certificates, it still works to http://localhost:3333 but when I tried to access https://localhost:3333, Chrome told me

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

how should I access https://localhost:3333?

Thanks!

Comment: What format are the key and cert?

Comment: rsa2048 I think

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I have a similar issue.  If I had to guess, the problem is that we are trying to use https (which is port 443) but defining a different port (3333 in your case).

Comment: have similar issue too, any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to solve this by switching to http:// which was fine for me because it was just a local server